# Array of string in c

Tags: c

Okay so as you can see I have a problem. I am trying to create an array of string in C with a function called tab_string. If you try to run the following code you will see that I have a segfault with the test number two and I don't know why because the first test work. Thanks in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NB_STRING 2

void create_tab_string(char chaine[], char*** p_tab_string) {
    char test[] = "Hey";
    char test2[] = "blabla";

    // Allocation 
    *p_tab_string = (char **)(malloc(NB_STRING*sizeof(char*)));

    // Test
    *p_tab_string[0] = test;
    printf("%s \n", *p_tab_string[0]);

    // Test 2 ERROR ?????
    *p_tab_string[1] = test2;
    printf("I have the second string \n");
    printf("%s \n", *p_tab_string[1]);  

}




int main() {
    int i;
    char string_test[] = "I am a test";
    char **tab_string;
    create_tab_string(string_test, &tab_string);
    for(i = 0; i < NB_STRING; i++)
        printf("%s \n", tab_string[i]);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Your test strings are local into function, not available outside the function scope.

Comment: You'd use `strdup` to assign test and test2 with your string

Answer (score 0):

Your function should be

```
void create_tab_string(char chaine[], char*** p_tab_string) {
    char *test = "Hey";
    char *test2= "blabla";

    // Allocation
    *p_tab_string = malloc(NB_STRING*sizeof(char*));

    // Test
    (*p_tab_string)[0] = test;
    printf("%s \n", (*p_tab_string)[0]);

    (*p_tab_string)[1] = test2;
    printf("I have the second string \n");
    printf("%s \n", (*p_tab_string)[1]);
}
```

First of all address of your test c-strings (arrays) are local to function and not accessible outside.
As you can see I changed them to simple pointers to string literals, so the strings literals are accessible outside the function.

Second thing are the way you are dereferencing your pointers.

Using `*p_tab_string[1]` you are dereferencing the second item of `p_tab_string` that does not exists.

Using `(*p_tab_string)[1]` you can dereference the second item of thing pointed by `*p_tab_string`, that is `tab_string` declare into `main`

Comment: Thank you very much. So the tab_string can't contain string initialize in create_tab_string ? Even if I use strdup ?

Comment: You can use `strdup`, but it doubles the memory in this specific case with string literals. Can be useful in other scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem of operator precedence.

You need to use:

```
(*p_tab_string)[1]
```

and not `*p_tab_string[1]`.

Also, as written in the comments your test strings are local into function, not available outside the function scope. You need to either duplicate them or use pointers.